# how to resize or growing partition root?

Tags: linux, fdisk

This is my current disk partition configuration

```
fd0      2:0    1    4K  0 disk 
sda      8:0    0  150G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  200M  0 part /boot
├─sda2   8:2    0  3.9G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0 34.2G  0 part /
└─sda4   8:4    0  1.8G  0 part /home
sdb      8:16   0   20G  0 disk 
sr0     11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

1. I would like to resize the root partition currently on `sda3`, and extend it onto the free space on `sdb`. After this, the size of my root partition would be 54.2G
2. if this free space (unallocated) existing in a disk and end of disk (number sectors are too many distance and above limit), who to do other method for this solution question.

------edited------
for additional info:

by fdisk:

```
# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sdb: 20 GiB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 150 GiB, 161061273600 bytes, 314572800 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2971e5ee

Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        2048   411647   409600  200M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2         411648  8515575  8103928  3.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3        8515584 80195583 71680000 34.2G 83 Linux                                                                                                                                       
/dev/sda4       80195584 83886079  3690496  1.8G 83 Linux
```

by parted:

```
(parted) p free                                                           
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 161GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system     Flags
        32.3kB  1049kB  1016kB           Free Space
 1      1049kB  211MB   210MB   primary  ext2            boot
 2      211MB   4360MB  4149MB  primary  linux-swap(v1)
        4360MB  4360MB  4096B            Free Space
 3      4360MB  41.1GB  36.7GB  primary  ext4
 4      41.1GB  42.9GB  1890MB  primary  ext4
        42.9GB  161GB   118GB            Free Space
```

## Note

unallocated sectors are not Back together Respectively

Comment: You have a 150GB disk and your root is 34.2 GB, you could use `resize2fs` to expand it if the rest of the disk is still unallocated, but you won't be able to extend on to the new hard drive. You should look at re-configuring to use LVM so as to benefit from resizable partitions (this would require a re-install, though)

Answer (score -1):

Use this below command to **increase/decrease** the file system size.

**`resize2fs device [new_size]`**

Refer this [link](https://linux.die.net/man/8/resize2fs) for more details

Comment: Does not match the asker's question. resize2fs works on a partition which is on the same disk as has free space. Asker is wanting to expand onto new disk

Comment: Additionally this assumes reiserfs, which the OP gives no indication is the FS in use. And such is rather unlikely given that reiserfs has been significantly declining in popularity.

Comment: i checked for resize to 140.2GB(34.2GB + 110GB unallocated) but return error -> resize2fs: Invalid new size: 144.2GB

Comment: Can you pls post the command which you used and sudo fdisk -l output